# Bash - check for multiple elements in array

Tags: bash, array

I'm just looking for a proper and more elegant way of writing the following code in Bash:

```
in_array() {
local somearray=${1}[@]
local somevalue=${2}
for i in ${!somearray}; do
    if [[ ${i} == ${somevalue} ]]; then
        return 0
    fi
done
return 1
}

#declare array
declare -a myArray=(foo bar baz qux)

#defined values
val1=foo
val2=baz

#Ugly check if multiple strings are part of the array at the same time 
if in_array myArray $val1 && in_array myArray $val2; then
    # Do something #
else
    # Do something else#
fi
```

The basic idea is that I need to check if 2 ore more static values are, at the same time, part of the array.
Wondering if there's a better way of doing this, because if I'll need to check for more than 3-4 values... that `if in_array` line will get huge.

Any suggestion, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Your script doesn't work. `"$(foo, bar, baz, qux)"` should probably have been `(foo bar baz qux)`, `$val22` should be `$val2`.

Comment: @choroba - sorry.. I should have checked better the syntax when posted. You are right

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177138/how-do-i-test-if-an-item-is-in-a-bash-array, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177433/66388, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366390/check-if-an-element-is-present-in-a-bash-array/14367368 ... pick one ...

Comment: @Hastur - please check my question again..

Comment: @MarinNedea _Any suggestion, please?_ `-->` check the answers from those links... for example when they suggest `=~` (for the ugliness - it's more readable ) or when they propose to _flatter_ the array and search the substring `*"two"*` (you can try  `*$var1*` && `*$var1*`) ... BTW I think you can agree _better_ is really relative... `:-)` better to read, better because more efficient (you need to use a different function as your answer... to break the 1st time you do not find...)...?

Comment: @Hastur Thank you for the suggestions. I'll check them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, array operations in bash are always ugly, as shown by your own way to pass the array to the function.

I would convert your test into a for loop over the arguments which remain after assigning the array:

```
in_array () {
    local somearray=${1}[@]
    shift
    for SEARCH_VALUE in "$@"; do
        FOUND=false
        for ARRAY_VALUE in ${!somearray}; do
            if [[ $ARRAY_VALUE == $SEARCH_VALUE ]]; then
                FOUND=true
                break
            fi
        done
        if ! $FOUND; then
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}
```

so you can check for the presence of all the values in a single function call:

```
arr=(1 2 3 4 5)
in_array arr 1 # 0
in_array arr 1 2 # 0
in_array arr 1 6 # 1
in_array arr 1 2 3 4 5 # 0
```